# How is BigDecimal represented in the JavaScript compiled by GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, bigdecimal

In GWT one can use `java.math.BigDecimal` in the client code. How are these BigDecimals represented in the resulting JavaScript code after compilation? Is there some extra class for that or do they use a native JavaScript object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigDecimal` has no special treatment by the GWT Compiler. It's emulated with a bunch of fields, with a small optimization for the case where the value is in the `java.lang.Double` (equivalent to a JS `Number`) value range; but from the point of view of JS code, it's an opaque `Object`.

See https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.7.0/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/math/BigDecimal.java#L523-L558

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimal` are serialized in their string representation. From the source code of `BigDecimal_CustomFieldSerializer`,

```
public static void serialize(SerializationStreamWriter streamWriter,
  BigDecimal instance) throws SerializationException {
    streamWriter.writeString(instance.toString());
}
```

Comment: This is about field serialization for client/server communication but not about the JavaScript code.